# <i> tag becomes clickable inside button element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that looks like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="yes">
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"> Yes</i> 
</button>
```

For some reason, the icon inside the button becomes clickable. So if I click on the icon it returns an error. But if I click the rest of the button it works.

If you are interested, here is the Javascript.

```
$('[id^=yes]').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

Any clues why?

Comment: can you use span instead of i?

Comment: you are missing `);`  in your script code at last. And i have checked your code. I din't get any error.Did you added jQuery library? check here:-https://jsfiddle.net/koufa7u9/

Comment: May be your external css or js causing these kind of troubles. Better use `span` instead of `i`

Comment: do you have any more code in your project which would affect the fa or fa-check classes?

Comment: Put code snippet for fast and clear answer

Comment: If this is actually reproducible, you could set `pointer-events: none` on the `i` tag ... `.fa { pointer-events: none }`

Comment: Sorry for the missing ); This was just in this post, not in the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `);` in your code.

Make sure jQuery library added before your script code.

Check below :-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[id^=yes]').on('click', function(e) {
      console.log(e.target);
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="yes">
    <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"> Yes</i> 
</button>
```

Working fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/7asu7rcc/

Note:- Wrap your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){...});` if your script code is on top of the page. If it's on bottom on the page then not needed.

***If you want that text will not become clickable then use:-***

```
.fa-check { pointer-events: none }
```

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

since `<i>` tag inside the button, it will be clickable. But if you want to separate out `<i>` tag click with the button click and stop fire the button click event you can have a solution like below

```js
$('[id^=yes]').on('click', function(e) {
    if(!$( event.target ).is( "i" )){
      console.log("button clicked");
    }
});
 
 $('[id^=yes-i]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("i tag clicked");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="yes">
    <i id="yes-i" class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"> Yes</i> 
</button>
```